# Converting an entire SQL DB to JSON

Tags: json, sql-server

Programming and SQL newbie here.

Im working with a single SQL DB that has many tables and i'm looking to output the entire DB to JSON.
I've found this doc that walks me through converting a single table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Now this may be a dumb question, but is there a way to get ALL the tables in the DB in a single query chaining "From [Table1],[Table2],..., is this recommended? Is there a better way of going about my task? Any advice and direction is appreciated.

Comment: `i'm looking to output the entire DB to JSON.` why? What are you trying to accomplish? What's the *actual* task? JSON is the worst possible format to transfer database data. It doesn't preserve any type information and is far more verbose than CSV. Both are far larger and slower than a plain-old database backup

Comment: This sounds like a really out-there idea! I could tell you how to do it, but it's almost certainly the wrong thing to be doing. A standard XY problem I think.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Very very good question... unfortunately I don't see a point in doing this either, but they prefer to work with json data and so here I am

Comment: Who's they and what does `prefer to work with json` mean? You can't replace a database with a JSON file, there's no way to identify objects by type, which you'll need to read a specific table's entities. If "they" want to load an entire database in memory, they can run a query without a filter. Not to mention indexing. Unless you have only a few 100s of (small) rows, working with such data will be extremely slow